# Rails 4 Error: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound Couldn't find 'id'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rubygems

I'm fairly new to rails and struggling on changing database values after the user successfully paid via stripe. Additionally after paying, it somehow redirects me everytime to '/subscriberjobs/1' where the following error appears. Instead it should direct to the root_path of the application.

This is the appearing error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in SubscriberjobsController#update
Couldn't find Job with 'id'=
```

Here is what I've got:

Routes

```
resources :subscriberjobs
resources :jobs
```

Jobs Controller

```
def new
  if current_user
    @job = current_user.jobs.build
  else
    redirect_to new_user_session_path
  end
end
def create
  @job = current_user.jobs.build(job_params)

  if @job.save
    redirect_to "/subscriberjobs/new?job_id=#{@job.id}"
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Subscriberjobs Controller (Here is what doesn't work!)

```
class SubscriberjobsController < ApplicationController

    before_filter :authenticate_user!

    def new
    end

    def update

        @job = Job.find(params[:job_id])

        token = params[stripeToken]

        customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
            card: token,
            plan: 1004,
            email: current_user.email
            )

        @job.is_active = true
        @job.is_featured = false
        @job.stripe_id = customer.id
        @job.save

        redirect_to root_path

    end
end
```

Form

```
= simple_form_for @job do |f|
    = f.input :company, required: true
    = f.input :title, required: true
    = f.input :job_filename
    = f.input :location, required: true
    = f.input :sort
    = f.input :tag_list, required: true
    = f.input :content_one
    = f.input :content_two
    = f.input :content_three
    = f.hidden_field :job_id, value: params[:id]
    = f.button :submit
```

Please tell me if you need additional information. Every answer is very appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
@job = Job.find(params[:job_id])
```

It looks, params[:job_id] is equal `nil`. Maybe your params `job_id` is called something different, for example `[:id]` ?

Other question is, why you updating `Job` in `SubscriberJobsController` ? Maybe will be bether if you use `JobsController` to do this ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm using this particular controller cause I only want to do this, if the user paid via stripe

Comment: I've added the form to the question and as far as I can see, it is actually called `job_id`

Comment: `= f.hidden_field :job_id, value: params[:id]` maybe this line not catching your params[:id] ?

Comment: Do you have something code in your  edit controller ?

Comment: You are right. I changed it to `[:id]`. Now I am getting this error instead though: `NameError in SubscriberjobsController#update
undefined local variable or method 'stripeToken' for #<SubscriberjobsController:0xaa4bbe0>`. I am not a Stripe expert but does it use the url for it's tokens?

Comment: instead this : `params[stripeToken]` put this: `params[:stripeToken]`

Comment: That does the trick, at least to prevent errors. But the main thing I am struggling on is that it still not updates the  params like `is_active`

Comment: try `@job.save!` instead `@job.save` to catch the errors.

Comment: That doesn't work either. I've tested it with `@job = Job.find(1)` and that works fine. So the issue is on extracting the id from this url: `http://localhost:3000/subscriberjobs/new?job_id=11`. Neither `@job = Job.find(params[:id])` nor `@job = Job.find(params[:job_id])` works for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try `params[:job][:id]`. Use View Source in the browser or e.g. Chrome dev tools to check how the form is rendered as it will tell you the parameters are being set. Also, watch the Rails log when you submit the form - you'll see what parameters are submitted.